# What's a good way to navigate code base and find source for a webpage

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to frontend development and thinking about what's a good way to find source code in our code base for a webpage. What I usually do is going to the element tab in chrome dev tool, finding a special class name, and searching that in code base to locate the file. I feel there should be better way for this task. I tried to use source tab in dev tool, but it shows tons of files and folders in navigation column. I also tried to use Components tab since we're using react, but component names are minified to single letters. So want to get suggestions from you folks. How do you usually do this? Thanks!

Comment: It is not as easy as you might think it is. Most JS applications are bundled into just a few JS files while compiling. So the original source file is more or less unknown.

Comment: What do you mean "find source code in our code base for a webpage"? Who owns the source code in the case you are asking about? Someone you know, or, do you mean, like, Google.com? In the former, you ask them for the source code, the latter, you don't get to know. If it's not publicly available on github or gitlab, you can't see the source code without asking the people who wrote it to give it to you. Or are you asking about navigating a code base that you already have?

Comment: @Multihunter Thx for your reply. I have access to the code base, but trying to to figure out what's a good way to locate a file for certain webpage.

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to clarify this? You are looking for help navigating a code base to find the code which created a specific page within a website. This is different to what Maximus and Rk Developer thought you meant.

Comment: @Multihunter Thx for your suggestion. I updated my question.

Comment: I would point out the inverse problem is even harder: Trying to navigate to a specific page on a website, representing a specific code file that you are looking at!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, the problem is that you are looking at the [minified](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/232588) (presumably production) version of the website. In general, while developing a website, you run a development server, in which all of the code (mostly) appears as it is written in your IDE/editor. That way you can find component names and inspect the source code through the chrome dev tools.

You should talk to whoever is currently responsible for the code to help you get a development server running on your machine. Then, you find the component names and then do a "find in files" search through your IDE/editor to see what they are, and where they are used in the code base. There may be many results that you have to sift through. That's par for the course in large code bases until you become more familiar with what goes where. And even afterwards.

I will say; even things that appear simple can be fiendishly complex, so it would be useful for you if the owner of the code could give you a rough outline of how things are organised and why to make navigating the code base easier. But, it will always be a bit hard, and depending on how clean the code is, it might be nearly impenetrable. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to to find source code or debug Code

> ①You can use Chrome dev tool
> ②You can use debbuger in VS
> ③you can　debug your code by puttin debugger in java script code
> ④browser has　good functionality to find
> code(For reference please check Image.)

[image]