# Navigate to the page on asp website where code is instantiated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, navigation, ascx

I have found several instances of a code element that needs to be updated in our codebase.

However, it's actually difficult to navigate to the relevant code on the website opened by the debugger.

The debugger opens a browser, e.g., Google chrome, and I need to find where the page I'm trying to update the code exists.  Specifically:
How can I find a specific word or phrase used as a code element in a page such as an .ascx file, or a JavaScript routine.
An example (one of many potential examples) would be:

```
MultipleCheckBoxes
```

on the website including its numerous subsites?

The coding folder contains a total of 2000 objects, and I am unsure of website "navigation tree" but I'm guessing there are at least dozens, possibly hundreds of pages and sub-pages.

This stack overflow question is essentially dealing with the inverse problem of going from the page to the code:

[What's a good way to navigate code base and find source for a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65591145/whats-a-good-way-to-navigate-code-base-and-find-source-for-a-webpage#comment133064457_65591145)

Comment: Are you truly working with an ASP.NET Web Site Project or just a web application in ASP.NET?

Comment: @TylerH:  Good catch.  It's a web application in ASP.NET.  I also edited the Tags of the question, based on your question.

Comment: If you're in Visual Studio, it's probably easier to do a search within the IDE. Its search function lets you specify its range to be an open solution or an entire project, among other options.

Comment: I already know how to search to find files containing the phrase in Visual Studio itself.  What I need to know for debugging and interaction with the people using the app is how to reach files such as .ascx files in the actual webpage opened via the browser via the debugger.

Comment: Well, you can step through code for a given page if you put in break-points. .And if you want to find all instances of "MultipleCheckBoxes", then try ctrl-shift-f, and filter by aspx and code pages.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal:  I can find them in the codebase easily enough.  I can add breakpoints to Javascript (but not always, sometimes they don't even add let alone really break).  The point of the question is to be able to navigate to the particular instances in the web browser opened by the debugger -- not to find them in coding files.  Apparently, this is not possible (see answer by TylerH)...

Comment: Ah very well- so keep in mind the shift ctrl f find option- huge help, despite this tip not what you're asking or looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot debug .ascx files from a browser; .ascx files are user controls that live within/are called from aspx pages in Web Forms projects; they are interpreted by the server, like .dll files, not by the client browser (even in a 'debug' mode).

You will need to search for this content from within Visual Studio or whatever IDE you are using. Visual Studio lets you search for keywords or phrases within the current page, all open pages, the current solution, or all solutions in the current project.